# mysql: new keyword not recognized on trigger creation

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-5.7

Working on `mysql.5.7`

Here is my `bugs` table

```
MySQL [jira_statistics]> describe bugs;
+---------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| issue_key                             | varchar(45)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| release_name                          | varchar(45)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| issue_summary                         | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| story_points                          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| qa_reopened                           | float        | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| done_reopened                         | float        | NO   |     | 0       |       |
```

This table is updated by periodic calls to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE bugs <file.csv>`

Whenever this update takes place (which may either update existing lines and/or insert new ones) I want another table that has some yielded statistics to be updated via the following trigger

```
create trigger update_bugs_stats after insert on `jira_statistics`.`bugs` for each row

begin

delimiter ;

 -- STORY POINTS -------------------------

SELECT AVG(story_points) INTO @avg_bugs_storypoints  FROM `jira_statistics`.`bugs` WHERE release_name = new.release_name;
SELECT MAX(story_points) INTO @max_bugs_storypoints FROM `jira_statistics`.`bugs` WHERE release_name = new.release_name;
SELECT MIN(story_points) INTO @min_bugs_storypoints  FROM `jira_statistics`.`bugs` WHERE release_name =  new.release_name;

INSERT INTO storypoints_stats (release_name, avg_bugs_storypoints, max_bugs_storypoints, min_bugs_storypoints)
VALUES (relName, @avg_bugs_storypoints, @max_bugs_storypoints, @min_bugs_storypoints)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    relName=new.release_name,
    avg_bugs_storypoints=@avg_bugs_storypoints,
    max_bugs_storypoints=@max_bugs_storypoints,
    min_bugs_storypoints=@min_bugs_storypoints;
```

However this gives me the following error whenever trying to create the trigger:

> Unknown column `new.release_name` in `where` clause.

Why isn't the `new` keyword bein recognized?

Comment: The delimiter statement should come before the trigger definition. I wonder if the selects are actually evaluated outside of the trigger, which would explain the error message (there is no NEW table outside of a trigger).

Answer (score 0):

Because new is reserved as a system word

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Please modify

```
new.release_name  ==> `new`.`release_name`
```

etc..

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the value of the `release_name` that was updated during the insert statement; that's why I am using the `new` keyword;

Comment: `new` is not actually a reserved word its a Keyword

Answer (score 0):

Τhe error was more stupid than I thought;

I was working directly on sql query editor and not on the triggers tab of mysql workbench so it did not parse correctly the `new` keyword`.

Comment: you better delete the query post than answering a non producible error